# Webkit animation not fading from nothing to solid

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-animations

I know I'm not using the CSS animation correctly but I'm struggling to find a web-kit transformation that will do what I need. I need the image (enter_button.png) to load with 0% opacity and then after 3 seconds fade into the solid 100% image. The current code I have is,

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>denby</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper_index">
            <div id="enter_button"> 
                <img src="images/enter_button.png" width="138" height="50" class="withfadeout" /> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
.withfadeout { 
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
} 
.withfadeout:hover { 
    -webkit-opacity: 0.25; 
    -moz-opacity: 0.25; 
    opacity: 0.25; 
}
#wrapper_index {
    height: 686px;
    width: 1024px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-image: url(images/entry_image-01.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
#enter_button {
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 431px;
    top: 413px;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 animations to achieve this.

```css
img { /* using generic img tag selector only for demo, change selector as appropriate */
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: load 3s 3s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: load 3s 3s linear forwards;
  animation: load 3s 3s linear forwards; /* adding mode as forwards makes the animation to retain its state as at the last keyframe */
  /* syntax is animation: animation-name animation-duration animation-delay animation-timing-function animation-fill-mode */
}
@-webkit-keyframes load {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  /* starts at opacity 0 */
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* ends at opacity 1 */
}
@-moz-keyframes load {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes load {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper_index">
  <div id="enter_button">
    <img src="https://www.google.com.sg/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="138" height="50" class="withfadeout" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The 3s delay in the above code would mean that the animation itself will start only after 3 seconds, so in total there would be 6 seconds for the image to become 100% solid. If you don't need a delay, you can just remove it.

**For Further reading:** [**MDN - CSS3 Animation Spec**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

Comment: perfect mate! thank you very much :) open my eyes to a whole type of CSS animation